# How to run a web service for multiple values

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I am trying to run a SOAP web service in soapUI with multiple values set but I am failing to achieve it. The question is how can I set multiple values for the given variable ID of the web service and get equally multiple results for every value. 
The wsdl file is given below:

```
      <soapenv:Body>
  <ws:getData>
     <ws:reportID>MY_DATA</ws:reportID>
     <ws:key>
        <xsd:type>ID</xsd:type>
        <xsd:value>8456321</xsd:value>
     </ws:key>
            <ws:dateInfo>
        <xsd:endDate>2016-05-24</xsd:endDate>
        <xsd:startDate>2016-05-30</xsd:startDate>
     </ws:dateInfo>
  </ws:getData>
```

You can see sample data below to be supplied to the value of ID via a CSV file or even through an interface to be read by a loop.

```
     6115120
     8126106
     0211110
     1212501
     6115120
     8126106
     0211110
     1212501
     6115120
     8126106
     0211110
     1212501
```

Comment: `Multiple values` - you mean `reportID, type`? If so, how do you get the data for these ? thru a file? Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I have all these IDs in a file and I want to pass them in the soap interface. Use a Loop or other script?

Comment: How does the data in file look like? Is it a csv file? A dummy data resembling your data would help to understand. By the way, does the data has column names?

Comment: yes CSV, export from an excel file. Alternatively how can I achieve this by passing 10 values through a loop or so?

Comment: Is csv file has column names? sample data please?

Comment: sample data given in the body of the message. It's just one column with or without name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145650/discussion-between-rao-and-ippokratis-karakotsoglou).

Comment: Soapui allows scripting, but I think you have to pay for that feature.  Other option is to use jmeter, which can also do all this, and is free.

Comment: @IPPOKRATISKARAKOTSOGLOU, have you got chance to try the solution?

Comment: @Rao, yes I tried the solution. I probably have a configuration error. Look the image in recent updates of the message.

Comment: @Rao, error: **Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI**

Comment: Looks you did not follow the answer carefully, requested you two create two steps, but you have only one. Just go thru answer one more time. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145650/discussion-between-rao-and-ippokratis-karakotsoglou

Comment: Indeed that is running correctly. Great job.

Comment: There is a problem though SOAP crashes and cannot get the results copied!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion, this comes under data driven test.

While data-driven test feature is provided by ReadyAPI (paid version of soapui) out-of-the-box, with the help of groovy script this can be done in free version as well.

For your case, create a test case with below steps:

- groovy script test step (proposed script below)
- soap request test step (which you have shown in the question)

Below is the script that needs to go in 1st step:

```
//Provide the path of your data file below
def datasource = 'C:/Temp/data.csv'

//Read all the lines
def lines = new File(datasource).readLines() 
lines.eachWithIndex { line, index -> 
//Get the data
    def data = line.toString().trim() 
    log.info "current data   : $data"
//Set the current row data into context variable called type
    context.type = data 

//Fire the webservice except last row of the data file as last row is execute automatically
     if (lines.size()-1 != index) { 
            step = context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex+1]
            step.run(testRunner, context)       
    } else {
        log.info 'last record'  
    }
}
log.info 'going to finish'
```

Make the below change in the soap request of the 2nd test step

Change from:

```
 <ws:key>
    <xsd:type>ID</xsd:type>
    <xsd:value>8456321</xsd:value>
 </ws:key>
```

**To:** using the context variable `type` which will be replaced in the loop each time with new row data

```
 <ws:key>
    <xsd:type>ID</xsd:type>
    <xsd:value>${type}</xsd:value>
 </ws:key>
```